# Slick-Util (in lwjgl): Importing a texture and displaying it results in weird, extra pixels (in lines) created near the texture

Tags: graphics, import, textures, lwjgl, image

Code: http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_1_-_Loading_Images_for_LWJGL

Output:

[image: code output]

(It's supposed to be just a rectangle; but the extra lines at the right, bottom, and the pixel at the bottom right appear.)

I tested it out with .jpg also, it appears that the only difference is that the line at the bottom acquires the same width as the rectangle to be displayed.

Can anyone help me with why / how to fix this / how to import an image correctly?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class TextureExample {

/** The texture that will hold the image details */
private Texture texture;


/**
 * Start the example
 */
public void start() {
    initGL(800,600);
    init();

    while (true) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        render();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(100);

        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Initialise the GL display
 * 
 * @param width The width of the display
 * @param height The height of the display
 */
private void initGL(int width, int height) {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width,height));
        Display.create();
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);               

    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);          

        // enable alpha blending
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GL11.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

/**
 * Initialise resources
 */
public void init() {

    try {
        // load texture from PNG file
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/image.png"));

        System.out.println("Texture loaded: "+texture);
        System.out.println(">> Image width: "+texture.getImageWidth());
        System.out.println(">> Image height: "+texture.getImageHeight());
        System.out.println(">> Texture width: "+texture.getTextureWidth());
        System.out.println(">> Texture height: "+texture.getTextureHeight());
        System.out.println(">> Texture ID: "+texture.getTextureID());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * draw a quad with the image on it
 */
public void render() {
    Color.white.bind();
    texture.bind(); // or GL11.glBind(texture.getTextureID());

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(),100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(),100+texture.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100+texture.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
}

/**
 * Main Class
 */
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    TextureExample textureExample = new TextureExample();
    textureExample.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution of textures need to be a power of two.  Once they are initialized, they can be resized to whatever dimensions are needed.